# Using a function to add a style

Tags: properties, undefined, addition

I'm using the same stuff i usually use to make functions work but for some reason it says "Cannot read property 'add' of undefined" and I have tried everything I know.

```
<input type=button id=b1 value="start" onclick=abc()>
<script>
function abc() {
document.getElementById("p2").classlist.add("hidden")
document.getElementById("pic1").classlist.remove('hidden')
document.getElementById("p1").classlist.add("hidden")
window.setimeout(sub1, 1000)
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`classlist` should be `classList`. Also, where you have `setimeout`, that should be `setTimeout`. Lastly, you are missing some quotation marks around property values for your input element, and missing semicolons at the end of your individual statements.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="b1" value="start" onclick="abc()">
<script>
  function abc() {
    document.getElementById("p2").classList.add("hidden");
    document.getElementById("pic1").classList.remove("hidden");
    document.getElementById("p1").classList.add("hidden");
    window.setTimeout(sub1, 1000);
  }
  
  function sub1() {
    console.log("called!");
  }
</script>

<div id="p2">This is the p2 div</div>
<div id="pic1" class="hidden">This is the pic1 div</div>
<div id="p1">This is the p1 div</div>
```